# iOS Changing .m to .mm = error

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to add box2D to my existing project. I think everything goes ok but when I add the

```
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "GLES-Render.h"
```

in the scene I want to use Box2D, and change the file extension from .m to .mm I get error in the CCLabelTTF , exactly one like this in each CCLabelTTF:

Cannot initialize a parameter of type CCTextAigment with an rvalue of type '

I don't know what to do in order to fix that error

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that CCLabelTTF was using **UITextAligmentCenter** that its no longer supported on iOS6 so instead of that, I used **kCCTextAlignmentCenter**